# How can I use htaccess to redirect URLs containing a specific word to 410 error?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-410

recently I develope a new cms and need to redirect **410** some urls that contains specific word which had been created from my old Cms

some url like the below

`https://www.domin.com/category-laptop/filter/minPrice-11000000/maxPrice-293000000/Attributes-41_3862-41_3940-41_3961-/page-2`

i need a code for Htaccess that when we have the **filter** Word in our url, redirect it to 410

for example

`https://www.domin.com/category-laptop/filter/minPrice-11000000/maxPrice-293000000`

return 410 redirect

or

`https://www.domin.com/category-laptop/filter/Attributes-41_3862-41_3940-41_3961-/page-2`

return 410 redirect

it doesn't matter where Filter keyword is located

#### **simpely i need a code in htaccess that redirect to 410 When url has the keyword : filter ,but when it does not exist do nothing**

i try this code but not work

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} filter RewriteRule .* - [R=410,L]`

`//i means if isset filter in url Redirect to 410`

or

`RewriteRule filter\/* [R=410,L]`

`//i means if isset filter and then everything after that,redirect to 410`
`o`r

`Redirect gone /*filter`

Comment: There is not query string in that URL, so no sense in trying to match "filter" in that. You simply want to match it in the actual requested path, so something like `RewriteRule filter - [R=410,L]` , I'd say ...